# Is it necessary to end a ThreadPool on Application.Exit()?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, threadpool, cancellation

I have a separate BackgroundWorker and ThreadPool that does methods in the background. (BackgroundWorker for UI feedback)

ThreadPool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(foo, null);
```

I understand that I need to safely terminate my BackgroundWorker using a flag considering that it gives me an Exception if ever I close it without one. However, the ThreadPool does not. (Closing doesn't throw any Exception)

BackgroundWorker_DoWork:

```
while (_isFinished)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

So is it necessary to do the same precaution with the ThreadPool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get your code example... if you have a loop that does a lot of work, why use the thread pool in the first place? Thread pooling is a solution for the overhead involved in spawning lots of threads. As for the closing thing - I always take matters into my own hands regarding everything that has to do with the lifetime of both the application and all the threads. The application can only end if all (worker) threads are joined. It's a basic design practice, that can save you a lot of misery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

[ThreadPool threads, according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx), are background threads and will not keep the application alive after the main execution thread has exited.  When the application exits, they stop executing as well.

Background threads also [do not throw exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx) if closed during application shutdown.